# How to automate changing my ip?

Tags: macos, shell-script

I am very new to OSX. I will use my MBP at work and home. I would like to be easily able to switch my ip when changing location.

Thus far I have dabbled with the automator, hoping to do something like this:

```
[pseudocode]

If IP = 192.168.0.10 root# changeip 192.168.0.10 10.0.0.15
else root# changeip 10.0.0.15 192.168.0.10
```

The reason for this is that my IP from home will not allow me access at work and vice versa. I have friends and family who drop in now and then, multiple wireless devices set up for the home IP range. Changing all of that to accommodate one new device (the Macbook) would make me reconsider my foray into OSX. I'd rather have the MBP adapt to me than I to it.

Comment: The first question- Why?

Comment: Why no DHCP? . .

Comment: more questions and still no answer?

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest reading the "[using network locations in Mac OS X](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT2712)" knowledge base entry on Apple's website.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using [Sidekick](http://oomphalot.com/sidekick/). It's a bit pricey at $29 but when I played around with the demo it seemed to work pretty well. It changes your settings based on your location, determined through Wifi.